# Is it a good practice to downvote an answer because of a minor English error?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I have answered a questions on Stack Overflow. But as I'm not that good in English, there was a little mistake. I used the word `round-up` instead of `round-down`. But I gave an example which anyone (well, who know some coding) can understand easily. The OP accepted my answer as the correct answer also.

But my problem is, that answer was downvoted because of that error. It was downvoted and there is this comment:

**I realize this might be a language issue, but this is erroneous. Rounding in general means to go to the closest number; rounding up means to go to a larger number, and rounding down means to go to a smaller number. It's incorrect to say each of your examples "rounds-up."**

Is it a good practice? As it seems, he does know that this is a language issue, and he understands what I was trying to say. Why didn't he

I know it is an error. But the user who downvoted it should easily edit that minor error instead of down-voting, right? Because as I see, the whole idea of Stack Overflow is to create a platform for users to learn, not to insult them because of their poor English.

As I can see, the **whole idea of this downvoting** was to **get his answer on top**, because the downvoted user also has an answer to the question. I do not think that's a good practice. It's **violating the voting policy** I guess.

**So what can I do now?**

Am I wrong here?

Is that user was correct?

Should I downvote answers (or questions) with minor English errors (Which I can understand) instead of editing it?

[This is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171497/math-ceil-and-math-rint-methods-returning-same-value/34171641)

Comment: Without having looked at the answer yet, I can nevertheless tell you with almost absolute certainty that minor English errors are not the only problem with it.

Comment: I've posted the link to the question. As I mentioned, I think he did this purposely to get his answer on top !

Comment: I wouldn't know.  There are no tools on Stack Overflow (available to users or moderators) that will identify single votes from one person to another.

Comment: As I suspected:  If you look at the comments below your answer you will see the *actual* reasons you were downvoted.

Comment: OK. But it is obvious I think. Because this question was inactive for 8 days and suddenly, my question was down-voted today with comment from a user who answered it. That's why I asked. Thanks

Comment: If 8 days have passed, it is unlikely that this is strategic voting (to "get his answer on top"), especially since your answer is the accepted one.

Comment: Yes. That's why I asked ? Is it good to down-vote because of a minor language issue ? Why didn't he edited it ?

Comment: Because he would have been changing the *meaning or intent* of your post, that's why.  That's not what editing is for.  Editing is for cleaning up spelling, punctuation and other "neatness" errors, not changing what other people say.

Comment: But question was down-voted today, and he commented today. Doesn't that mean he down-voted it ?

Comment: I wouldn't know.  There are no tools on Stack Overflow (available to users or moderators) that will identify single votes from one person to another.

Comment: @RobertHarvey OK so. I got you. Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are different "minor" errors with English grammar that could have arisen here;  one that has to do with the structure of the sentence, and the other which has to do with the *intent* of the sentence.

Fixing structure is easy since it doesn't change the intent.  However, the way your answer was phrased made it seem more like the *intent* was wrong.

I can't say whether or not you had intended to say, "rounds to the nearest integer", so the only actions I have to take are to downvote and comment, pointing out the error of your ways.

Is it a good thing to do this?  **Yes!** It got your attention and drove you to fix it instead of leaving it in an erroneous state.

Now, if this were *just* an error with the structure of the sentence, including one that had a few typos, then perhaps an edit would have been in order.  But in this scenario, that sort of judgment call isn't clear-cut.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !